# How can I have each of my Flask Apps write to Individual Logs?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, logging

I want to get individual logs working for each of my apps in Flask.

In main.py, I have the following:

```
from flask import Flask
from my_app1 import my_app1_page
from my_app2 import my_app2_page

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(my_app1_page)
app.register_blueprint(my_app2_page)
```

In my_app1.py, I have the following:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

# Special Python variable containing the name of the current module:
app = Flask(__name__)
# Here we are loading the config from a central config.py
app.config.from_object('config')
# This is a blueprint used in main, so we define it below:
lint_page = Blueprint('my_app1_page', __name__)

# page, route and app logic
```

It's the same with my_app2.py:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
# Here we are loading the config from a central config.py
app.config.from_object('config')
# This is a blueprint used in main, so we define it below:
lint_page = Blueprint('my_app2_page', __name__)

# page, route and app logic
```

This way, I can stand up individual apps with their *.py pages and just register them in main.py.

What I want is to have logging in each app that writes to its own log.  So any logs generated in my_app1.py would write to `logs/my_app1.log`.

This code kinda works:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_file = 'logs/my_app1.log'
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)

logger.debug("Someone requested the my_app1 page!")
```

It creates the file, `logs/my_app1.log` but it doesn't write anything.  I tried opening up the permissions to 666, but that also didn't work.  I want to write something that I can just paste into each app and change a few values to make the log specific to this app portion of Flask.

**Things I have tried:**

- I have tried reading the logging guide. It gives basic logging, but talks about root logging and such and handlers. It was a bit confusing and whatever code I used there did not seem to work for me.
- I have tried ChatGPT and it gave me ideas on how to get it half working.
- I checked other Stackoverflow questions and they mention that logging is handled directly in Flask using app.logger. I did give this a try, but I still have empty log files.

Would someone be able to help point me in the right direction to get logging for each of my apps? I know I should add some rotation and I plan on doing that, but for now I really just want to get it working at proof of concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that your created FileHandler is not linked to the logger object.
In your code, the file_handler is never added to the logger. You have to add the line `logger.addHandler(file_handler)` accordingly.

###### my_app1.py

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_file = 'logs/my_app1.log'
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)

logger.debug('logger app1') # Will be logged in logs/my_app1.log
```

###### my_app2.py

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_file = 'logs/my_app2.log'
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)

logger.debug('logger app2') # Will be logged in logs/my_app2.log
```

Comment: You are a scholar and and a gentleperson! Thanks so much for this! It works.

I also noticed that I was not passing my formatter into the handler.  Did this with:
`file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)`